# Better way to access Laravel array inputs?

Tags: arrays, laravel, input

Currently I have an array `sort`.  Sort has only one key / value.  The keys and values are always different.  This array always has just 1 key/value pair.  How do I access both elements dynamically in laravel?

I have already solved this but think it is extremely inefficient.

**my current solution**

I made a function `orderQuery()` to return the key name.

```
function orderQuery() {
    foreach (Input::get('sort') as $key => $value) {
        return $key; // there is only 1 item in the array but this looks like bad practice
    }
}
```

Then I call it like this to respond to my request

`->orderBy(orderQuery(), Input::get('sort.'.orderQuery()))`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`key()`](http://php.net/key)

```
$key = key(Input::get('sort'));
```

If you want to be save `reset` the pointer first:

```
$sort = Input::get('sort');
reset($sort);
$key = key($sort);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems much cleaner and better practice. I am using `$value = Input::get("sort.$key");` to get the value from key now.  :)